# Retrieving values from grid squares using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a map of Europe, with grid squares that each have vales for temperature. I need to have a list of all the temperature values for each country. 
Instead of hovering my mouse over each relevant grid square and manually writing down the values, is there a way I can select and retrieve a list of all in the selection?

It's also ECMWF data if that helps.

Comment: What is the file type? Is it a vector, raster, or a mesh? If vector select and look in the attribute table. If Raster you could create a set points and have them pick up the values. I am not familiar enough with grid data to know the process.

Comment: If you can provide a link to the specific dataset you are using I will be able to provide an answer